# Non-split extensions of $GL_n(F_q)$ by $F_q^n$ ?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-fields, finite-groups

A very naive question :
I just learned that there is a non-split extension of $GL_3(F_2)$ by $F_2^3$ (with standard action). It can be realized as the subgroup of the automorphism group $G_2$ of Cayley-Graves octaves (edit: octonions) that preserve up to sign the basis $e_i$, $i=1..7$of imaginary octaves. Does this happen for other values of $(n,q)$ (as in the title) ?

Comment: Shouldn't this essentially always happen? Look at $V$ an $n$ dimensional vector space over $F_q$.  Take the collection of affine transformations.  This is a group, and it's an extension of this sort (or do I have the order backwards?) and it won't be split.

Comment: The affine transformations are a semidirect product, so the exact sequence does split.

Comment: By the way, what are Cayley-Graves octaves?

Comment: I assume the OP means the octonions.  

Comment: Ahh.  I'm never quite sure what the words mean in nonabelian categories.  I thought that for an exact sequence to be split it had to be precisely the product of the two groups, with the inclusion map from coproduct and the projection map from the product structure.

Comment: Sorry, I said Cayley-Graves to avoid ambiguity, and spread it instead. I meant octonions, the only eight-dimensional normed division algebra over the reals.
 

Comment: Charles, for groups and modules, the meaning is the same: an extension $A\to B\to C$  splits if the second map admits a right inverse $C\to B.$

Comment: @Victor: Yes, but for modules this is equivalent to saying, that $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0\cong 0\to A\to A\oplus C\to C\to 0$ so one can use this property as definition of "split" too. For groups this is not equivalent.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This never happens for finite fields $F \neq \mathbb{F}_2$.  If a group $G$ acts on an abelian group $M$, then short exact sequences

$1 \rightarrow M \rightarrow \Gamma \rightarrow G \rightarrow 1$

are classified by elements of $H^2(G;M)$.  It is thus enough to show that if $F \neq \mathbb{F}_2$ is a finite field and $V = F^n$, then $H^2(GL_n(F);V)=0$.  In fact, we will show that $H^k(GL_n(F);V)=0$ for all $k$.

We have a short exact sequence

$1 \rightarrow F^{\times} \rightarrow GL_n(F) \rightarrow PGL_n(F) \rightarrow 1.$

Associated to this is the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence in cohomology with coefficients in $V$.  The $E_2$-term is $H^p(PGL_n(F);H^q(F^{\times};V))$.  The key fact here is that $H^q(F^{\times};V)=0$ for all $q$.

On page 58 of Brown's book on group cohomology, there is a calculation of the cohomology of finite cyclic groups with nontrivial coefficients.  In the case we're considering, it goes as follows.  Define $N = \sum_{x \in F^{\times}} x \in \mathbb{Z}[F^{\times}]$ (of course, $N$ acts as $0$ on $V$, but forget that for the moment).  We then get a map $N : V \rightarrow V$ whose image lies in the ring of invariants $V^{F^{\times}}$ and which satisfies $N(gv)=N(v)$ for all $g \in F^{\times}$ and all $v \in V$.  Let $V_{F^{\times}}$ be the ring of coinvariants, ie the quotient of $V$ by the subspace spanned by $\langle g v-v\ |\ g \in F^{\times},\ v \in V\rangle$.  We get an induced map $\overline{N}:V_{F^{\times}} \rightarrow V^{F^{\times}}$.  The result then is that $H^0(F^{\times};V) = V^{F^{\times}}$, that $H^i(F^{\times};V) = ker\ \overline{N}$ for $i \geq 1$ odd, and that $H^i(F^{\times};V) = coker\ \overline{N}$ for $i \geq 1$ even.  But clearly $V^{F^{\times}} = 0$, and since $F$ is not the field with $2$ elements we also have $V_{F^{\times}} = 0$.  The result follows.

Comment: In this case $N=0$ on $V$

Comment: I think your argument works with $F^{\times}$ (which is also a cyclic subgroup of $GL_n(F)$) instead of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, if $F \neq \mathbb{F}_2$. Let $N = \sum_{t \in F^{\times}} t$ and $D=s-1$ where $s$ is a generator of $F^{\times}$. If $F \neq \mathbb{F}_2$, it is easy to check that $N=0$ and $D$ is a nonzero scalar. Then $H^0(F^{\times},V)=0$ and for $i \geq 1$, $H^i(F^{\times},V)= \ker D / \im N$ if $i$ is even, $\ker N / \im D$ if $i$ is odd (noncanonically), and both are zero. So the only possible case is $\mathbb{F}$_2

Comment: I don't know how to edit, so it's $\ker D / \mathrm{im} N$ and $\ker N / \mathrm{im} D$, and a reference for this is Serre's Local fields, ch. VIII, § 4

Comment: Good point Homology!  I'll revise it to prove the more general result.  I'm so used to working with GL_n(Z) that I sometimes forget that GL_n(R) can have central elements other than -1...

Comment: and for $q=2$, $n$ large, it doesn't happen, either, according to Betley. http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1004602

Comment: The paper is about homology (not cohomology), how do you make it work?

Comment: @Homology : You can use the following duality (see Prop VI.7.1 in Brown's book).  If $M$ is an abelian group, define $M'=Hom(M,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$.  Then if $M$ is a finite rank $G$-module, we have $H^k(G;M')=(H_k(G;M))'$.

Comment: So, I understand that it is a char 2 phenomenon. 
Does it happens in higher dimensions (and char 2)?

Comment: @BS : I haven't had a chance to read Betley's paper carefully, but if Ben Wieland is correct, then the answer is that it can only happen in low dimensions.  I'm not sure how small "low" means here.

Comment: Andy's argument is not about char 2, but about nontrivial units; it applies to every field but $\mathbb F_2$. I think Dwyer proves $n=6$ suffices (leaving $n=4,5$ up in the air), but that's probably pessimistic. Incidentally, my notes say that Quillen proved that $H_k(GL_n(F);\mathbb Z)$ stabilizes about when $n=k$ for all fields except $\mathbb F_2$. For $\mathbb F_2$, you need $n=2k+1$.

Comment: I've been fighting with gap and the hap package to compute the H^2 when n is small, but it seems it is not possible with this package (it is more or less restricted to trivial actions...).

Comment: Computing H^2 of even modestly sized finite groups with twisted coefficients is pretty computationally intensive.  The real problem is that a 2-cocycle is not determined by its values on a generating set for the group, so you have to actually keep track of EVERY pair of elements of the group.  An amusing size effect of this is a theorem of Gordon that says that there is no algorithm for computing even untwisted H^2 of a group given by generators and relations (of course, it is easy to compute twisted H^1 of such a group...).

Comment: You could use the "cohomolo" package for n ≤ 6.  H^2(GL(n,2),2^n) has dimension 1 when n=3,4,5, and 0 for n=1,2,6.  Perhaps those calculations suffice.  In case you are curious, H^1(GL(n,2),2^n) has dimension 1 when n=3, and 0 for n=1,2,4,5,6,7,8.  You definitely don't need to keep track of every pair for a cocycle.  For GL(n,2), you only need polynomially many values in n, even if you want to efficiently to compute any other value (and not just know it is determined).  I think C*n^4 should suffice, and the calculations to get the cohomology are somewhere in the n^8 to n^12 range.

Comment: @Jack : Interesting!  Can you recommend some good references for those types of calculations?  The only source I know is Holt-Eick-O'Brien, and I remember them saying that computing H^2 was pretty intense (though I haven't looked through that book in a while).

Comment: As a side note, this might be the longest on-topic comment thread I've seen in a long time!  Though this comment probably breaks that...

Comment: I think most of it is folklore.  H^2 is harder than H^1.  H^1 depends on the number of generators, H^2 more on the number of relations (rewrite rules).  In the soluble world, the number of rewrite rules is the square of the number of generators (composition length). In the finite world, if the field size of composition factors is bounded, then the number of rewrite rules stays polynomial in the max rank and composition length. Squier, Groves, and Anick described using rewriting systems for cohomology, but I guess people didn't know it actually worked until recently.

Comment: G a group, X a generating set, f:G→X* a set-theoretic section of the evaluation X*→G such that f(G) is closed under subwords, V a G-module.  Only consider transversals of V defined by the preimages of elements of X.  Then a cocycle is completely determined by its values on X×G, and in fact it is almost constant.  The only values needed are on (x,g) where xf(g) is not in the image of f.  Pairs (xf(g),f(xg)) are called rewrite rules. This allows very efficient compression of cocycles, and evaluation on (g,h) is polynomial in the length of f(g) as long as one has an oracle to compute f.

Comment: Many thanks to Andy and Jack for your very interesting answer and comments. This is definitely an answer !

Answer (score 16):

There is a famous non-split extension called the "Dempwolff group", $2^5 \cdot GL_5(2) = 2^5 \cdot SL_5(2)$. And apparently this is the largest case for which it happens, as you can see from the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dempwolff_group.

If you consider $SL_n$ rather than $GL_n$, there are more non-split extensions, for example $5^3 \cdot SL_3(5)$.

Comment: If I could, I would credit you the answer, since it completely answers my question.

Answer (score 11):

There's an elementary (non-cohomological) group-theoretic explanation for why $GL(n,q)$ must split over its natural module in odd characteristic. Suppose $N \triangleleft G$, where
$G/N \cong GL(n,q)$ with $q$ odd and $N$ is isomorphic to the natural module for $G/N$. The negative of the identity matrix in $GL(n,q)$ is a central element of order $2$ that acts on $N$ with no nonidentity fixed points. Thus there exists $T \triangleleft G$ with
$N \subseteq T$ such that $T/N$ has order $2$, and if $S$ is a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $T$ then ${\bf C}_N(S) = 1$. Now let $K = {\bf N}_G(S)$. By the Frattini argument,
$G = TK = NSK = NK$. Also, $N \cap K = 1$ since $T$ must centralize $N \cap K$. Thus $K$ is the desired complement for $N$ in $G$.

Comment: This is a very nice argument, and it seems to me that it works for all $q>2$: just replace $-I$ by $aI$ where $a\in \mathbf{F}_q^*$ has prime order $p$ (multiplicatively, so $p$ divides $q-1$).

Comment: @Ladisch--Right. I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 5):

I'm writing this as an "answer" because (a) there are a number of comments,
and (b) I don't know if it would fit in a comment.

Let $F$ a finite field, and let $V$ a finite dimensional $F$-vector space,
and view $V$ as an $F^\times$-module via multiplication.
Then as pointed out in Andy Putman's answer, $H^i(F^\times,V) = 0$ for all $i \ge 0$
provided $|F| > 2$.

Well, it is clear enough under the assumption $|F|>2$ that $H^0(F^\times,V) = V^{F^\times} = 0$. For the higher cohomology
vanishing, there is no need to use the description of "cohomology of cyclic groups" to obtain this vanishing; the point is just that $|F^\times|$ is invertible
in $F$. Use the following generality:

Let $H$ be a subgroup of finite index $n$ in a group $G$. If  $M$ is a $\mathbf{Z}G$-module,
then $\operatorname{Cor} \circ \operatorname{Res}$ is multiplication by $n$ on $H^\bullet(G,M)$, where $\operatorname{Cor}:H^\bullet(H,M) \to H^\bullet(G,M)$
denotes the corestriction and $\operatorname{Res}:H^\bullet(G,M) \to H^\bullet(H,M)$ the restriction;
see e.g. Serre's *Local Fields* VII.7, VIII.2.

Let now $k$ be a commutative ring (with 1), suppose that $H=1$ and that
$n = [G:1]= |G|$ is invertible in $k$.  If $M$ is a $kG$-module (i.e.
a $k$-module with $k$-linear $G$ action), then all $H^i(G,M)$ are $k$-modules
and $H^i(H,M) = H^i(1,M) = 0$ for $i>0$. For $i>0$, the preceding result shows these $k$-modules to be annihilated by the unit
$n$ of $k$; thus $H^i(G,M) = 0$ for $i>0$.

To apply this result in the original setting, take $k=F$, $M=V$ and $G=F^\times$; we find that $H^i(F^\times,V) = 0$ for $i>0$.

Comment: For some strange reason, mathematicians have trouble spelling my last name...

Comment: oops -- very sorry about that! (Thanks for the edit...)

Comment: And a completely straightforward generalization of Andy's argument: Let $R$ be a ring and $V$ an $R$-module. When can we say $H^i(Aut(V),V)=0$ for all $i$? It's enough if $Aut(V)$ has a normal subgroup $G$ such that $H^i(G,V)=0$ for all $i$. As long as no nonzero element of $R$ annihilates $V$, the units in the center of $R$ will inject into the center of $Aut(V)$. So then it suffices if $R$ has a central element $u$ such that both $u$ and $1-u$ are units. Here $u$ may have finite or infinite order.

Comment: @AndyPutman's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/29422) referenced above.